# Import a string value from first loop to second loop in template?

Tags: django, django-templates

Is it able to import a string value from first loop to second loop in template?

In second loop, "mydata.data.room" should be mydata.A.room, mydata.B.room, mydata.C.room and mydata.D.room

---

In dictionary

```
{'mydata': {u'A': {'room': [u'1-1']},
            u'B': {'room': [u'1-1', u'1-2']},
            u'C': {'room': [u'1-1', u'1-2', u'1-3']},
            u'D': {'room': [u'1-1']}}
```

---

In template

```
{% for data in mydata %}
    <div id="{{ data }}" class="tab-pane fade">
    {% for room in mydata.data.room  %}
            <h3>{{ room }}</h3>
            <p>Some content.</p>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
{% for i,j in mydata.items %}
    <div id="{{ i }}" class="tab-pane fade">
    {% for room in j.room  %}
        <h3>{{ room }}</h3>
        <p>Some content.</p>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code won't work. I'm guessing that what you want to do is:

In the python code:

```
mydict = {'mydata': {u'A': {'room': [u'1-1']},
        u'B': {'room': [u'1-1', u'1-2']},
        u'C': {'room': [u'1-1', u'1-2', u'1-3']},
        u'D': {'room': [u'1-1']}}
```

In the template code:

```
{% for key, data in mydict.mydata.items %}
        <div id="{{ key }}" class="tab-pane fade">
        {% for room in data.room  %}
                <h3>{{ room }}</h3>
                <p>Some content.</p>
        {% endfor %}
        </div>
{% endfor %}
```